# passing parameters (Prob with std::string conversion to LPWSTR)

Tags: c++, winapi

thats a little bit annoying. I try to passing parameters from an `NPAPI` plugin to an EXE.

**First information:** The executable is currently a **placeholder** and prints out only the passed arguments as an message box:

```
int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    /* Print out the arguments */
    MessageBox(NULL, lpCmdLine, TEXT("World of RPG"), NULL);

    /* Exit with return code 0x00 */
    return 0;
}
```

When i try to start the Application over Visual Studio (started with the parameter "-console"), the message box will prompted correctly:

[image]
[image]

Yet, i try to execute the executable from my `NPAPI` Plugin:

```
/* Javascript call: document.getElementById("myPlugin").startGame("-console"); */
std::string WoRPGAPI::startGame(const std::string& method_args) {
    /* Define JSON result variables */
    FB::VariantMap json;
    Json::StyledWriter writer;

    /* Define process variables*/
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation = { 0 };
    STARTUPINFO startupInfo = { 0 };
    startupInfo.cb = sizeof(startupInfo);

    LPWSTR game_exe = LgetGamePath("World of RPG.exe").c_str(); // example: "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\World of RPG\\World of RPG.exe"
    LPWSTR game_args = method_args.c_str(); // example: "-console"

    /* Create the Process */
    BOOL status = CreateProcess(game_exe, game_args, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &startupInfo, &processInformation);

    /* Check the process status */
    if (!status) {
        DWORD dLastError = GetLastError();
        LPCTSTR strErrorMessage = NULL;

        FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS | FORMAT_MESSAGE_ARGUMENT_ARRAY | FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER, NULL, dLastError, 0, (LPWSTR)&strErrorMessage, 0, NULL);

        json["code"] = dLastError;
        json["message"] = strErrorMessage;
    }

    json["status"] = status;

    /* get JSON back to the browser */
    return writer.write(FB::variantToJsonValue(json));
}
```

And here is the result:

[image]

Ok, try to test with an longer string with `startGame("This is a longer string!")`. You see, only the first word will be cutten. I've tried over 30 mins to solve that:

[image]

Can you tell me, what i'm doing wrong?
I've tried a lot of conversion examples to convert `std::string` to `LPWSTR` but nothing works. Other methods gave me cryptical output like chinese characters.

Comment: The cast in your very first line of code is wrong. You should be able to pass `lpCmdLine` directly to the `MessageBox` function. If not, you need to recompile with the `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` symbols defined. Once that's fixed, you'll want to switch over to `std::wstring` instead of `std::string`. Your problems are the classic symptoms of trying to mix wide and narrow strings, but instead of converting you're trying to cast. That isn't the same, the compiler is warning you for a reason.

Comment: **Is** all the time in unicode (both applications)!  `/Yu"stdafx.h" /GS /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /ZI /Gm /Od /sdl /Fd"Debug\vc120.pdb" /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_LIB" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /D "_AFXDLL" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /Oy- /MDd /Fa"Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Debug\" /Fp"Debug\World of RPG.pch"`

Comment: A directly call over cmd or batch-File works: `"World of RPG.exe" -console`

Comment: Get rid of all the casts! Every time you use a cast, you should strongly suspect you are doing something seriously wrong, because most of the time you are. And in the very rare case you are not, you should at least use the C++ restricted casts – function-style cast, `const_cast`, `static_cast`, `dynamic_cast` or `reinterpret_cast`. In addition to being likely wrong, code with casts, especially C-style ones, is also completely **unreviewable**. I simply can't tell from the code what the actual types are and therefore can't tell you whether the casts are correct or not. -1.

Comment: @JanHudec **Sorry** that i'm currently learning C++. I'm comes from Java/PHP.

Comment: @AdrianPreuss: Everybody learns sometime. So just take it as advice. The C-style cast is dangerous, because it does different things for different kinds of values and that leads to errors. So try rewriting the code to get rid of the casts and ask specific questions about how to convert particular value. This is actually a bit too long to find the problematic bit.

Comment: @JanHudec Yep, everybody. And that is why you gave me -1? You can also tell me that I am going in a wrong direction. Most languages not really strict - here you can cast types as you want, but as you say not in C++ (I have now learned now through you). Nevertheless, I am still looking for ways to switch between different data types such as `std::string` to `LPWSTR`.

Comment: @AdrianPreuss: I gave you -1, because I couldn't really tell from the question which bits are actually wrong. As for languages that are not strict; you can cast types as you want, but most of the results will be totally bogus. It's true about both C and C++, but in C you often have to cast and know whether it's correct yourself while in C++ you can avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `MessageBox` function takes two arguments correctly typed as `LPCTSTR`. Assuming unicode that is equal to `LPCWSTR` or `wchar_t const *`.
2. Under unicode, you shouldn't<sup>1</sup> work with `std::string` at all. It is based on `char` and you will need `wchar_t`-based string everywhere.
3. The `std::wstring` is based on `wchar_t`, so you want to use that.
4. Since the arguments are properly const, `MessageBox` will accept result of `std::wstring::c_str()` without casting.

Note, that many of the casts in your code are unnecessary. Let's start with:

```
/* convert/cast LPTSTR to LPCWSTR */
LPCWSTR test = (LPCWSTR) lpCmdLine;
```

`LPCWSTR` is `wchar_t const *` and if you have unicode set (as you seem to), `LCTSTR` is `wchar_t *`. And adding `const` is *implicit* conversion in C++. So

```
test = lpCmdLine;
```

will do the same. Without risking an error by not having unicode selected, in which case `LCTSTR` expands to `char *` and the statement would fail with "cannot convert to incompatible pointer type" error. With the cast it compiles, but since the C-style cast does a reinterpret cast, i.e. treats the memory content as the requested type, the result is garbage.

Now what I don't understand is this:

```
BOOL status = CreateProcess((LPWSTR) LgetGamePath("World of RPG.exe").c_str(), game_args, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &startupInfo, &processInformation);
```

The function `LgetGamePath` gets a narrow string (wide literals have `L` prefix, which can also be generated with the `TEXT()` macro), so I would expect it to return a *narrow* string (you don't seem to show that signature, so I don't know for certain). Now you blindly cast it to wide, which will yield garbage and it shouldn't be able to start the process. On the other hand the conversion of the arguments actually seems correct, as long as the string is ASCII only.

<sup>1</sup><sub>For portable programs `wchar_t` is still a mess, because it is 4 bytes on some platforms and 2 bytes on others (including windows that eagerly created wide versions of all interfaces when 2 bytes were enough and were stuck with 2 bytes when Unicode exceeded it). And at least for input and output you usually need a specific encoding, which is often Utf-8 (due to it's backward compatibility with ASCII, but Windows don't support it). So many people, including me, when writing portable programs just prepare conversion functions for calling system interfaces somewhere and work in Utf-8 (like e.g. Gtk) or Utf-16 (stored in `uint16_t`, not `wchar_t`, as do Qt or ICU) internally.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your answer. On `CreateProcess` you can use `TEXT`, right, i wrote the method `LgetGamePath` to get the Path from the Windows-Registry.

Comment: @AdrianPreuss: Yes, but does the method really _return wide_ while _taking narrow_ string? Because if not, you have some serious undefined behaviour there in the cast.

Comment: Okay. Good, you say i can't work with `std::string` and i should use instead  of that, `std::wstring` correct? Have change that but the first word on the MessageBox is still cutted.