# Populate a Virtual ListView with std::vector<std::string>

Tags: c++, listview, winapi, vector

I have a vector of thousands of strings:

```
std::vector<std::wstring> a;
```

filled with some algorithms.

Following the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44790632/1-million-row-listview), here is how I create a `ListView` as a "virtual list":

```
hList = CreateWindowEx(0, WC_LISTVIEW, L"", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LVS_REPORT | LVS_OWNERDATA, 0, 0, 800, 400, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_LISTVIEW, hInst, NULL);

LV_COLUMN lvcol;
...
ListView_InsertColumn(hList, 0, &lvcol);

ListView_SetItemCountEx(hList, 100000, LVSICF_NOSCROLL);

...

// in the message loop
case WM_NOTIFY:
    pdi = (NMLVDISPINFO*) lParam;
    pi = pdi->item;
    switch (pdi->hdr.code)
    {
        case LVN_GETDISPINFO:
        {
            pi.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
            pi.pszText = a[pi.iItem];    // the nth item should be the nth string in the vector
        }
    }
```

I tried a lot of variations on:

```
pi.pszText = a[pi.iItem];
```

but they all failed with such kind of errors:

> Error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'std::basic_string,std::allocator>' to 'LPWSTR'

What could help to do this?

---

Note: in fact I would like to display on row `n` of the `ListView` : the n*th* string of vector `a` concatenated with the number `n`, like this `Blabla217` on the row 217.

Note2: even after Igor's suggestion (i.e. a cast `pi.pszText = LPWSTR(a[pi.iItem].c_str());`), the ListView is still empty, instead of displaying elements.

Comment: You are building a Unicode built. The control wants Unicode strings. Could you have a `std::vector<std::wstring>` instead? Then you would write `pi.pszText = a[pi.iItem].c_str();`

Comment: Ah. Just cast: `pi.pszText = LPWSTR(a[pi.iItem].c_str());`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [passing parameters (Prob with std::string conversion to LPWSTR)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23591748/passing-parameters-prob-with-stdstring-conversion-to-lpwstr)

Comment: What's pi? Looks like a local variable. You need to return the string in the structure passed to you in the notification message.

Comment: @Basj: Per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774780.aspx): "*If the `LVITEM` structure is **receiving item text**, the `pszText` and `cchTextMax` members specify the address and size of a buffer. You can either copy text to the buffer or assign the address of a string to the `pszText` member. In the latter case, you must not change or delete the string until the corresponding item text is deleted or two additional `LVN_GETDISPINFO` messages have been sent.*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  don't really know why, but this solved it:

```
case WM_NOTIFY:
    pdi = (NMLVDISPINFO*) lParam;
    //pi = pdi->item;
    switch (pdi->hdr.code)
    {
        case LVN_GETDISPINFO:
        {
            //pi.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
            pdi->item.mask = LVIF_TEXT;;
            //pi.pszText = a[pi.iItem];   
            pdi->item.pszText = a[pi.iItem];   
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exact sure about the problem you're facing, but one thing for sure, you're passing multi-byte string (`std::string`, using `char`) while it is asking for wide-char string (`std::wstring`, using `WCHAR`).

Here is a handy code that converts `std::string` to `std::wstring`.

```
inline std::wstring WideFromMulti(
    std::string const & multi,
    UINT codepage)
{
    int cchWide = MultiByteToWideChar(codepage, 0, multi.c_str(), -1, nullptr, 0);
    LPWSTR szWide = new wchar_t[cchWide];
    MultiByteToWideChar(codepage, 0, multi.c_str(), -1, szWide, cchWide);
    std::wstring wide(szWide);
    delete[] szWide;
    return wide;
}

inline std::wstring WideFromUtf8(
    std::string const & utf8)
{
    return WideFromMulti(utf8, CP_UTF8);
}
```

Then you can get `LPCWSTR` by `c_str()`.

```
std::string test_str;
std::wstring test_wstr = WideFromUtf8(test_str);
LPCWSTR wszTest = test_wstr.c_str();
```

What about `LPWSTR`? Well if you're sure that the string won't get modified, you can cast it by `const_cast<LPWSTR>(wszTest)`. If you're strongly against `const_cast`, you may create a temporary copy of `LPWSTR` like this:

```
std::wstring test(L"Hello world");
LPCWSTR szTestConst = test.c_str();
int cchMax = ::lstrlenW(szTestConst) + 1;
std::vector<WCHAR> v(cchMax);
::lstrcpynW(&v[0], szTestConst, cchMax);
LPWSTR szTest = &v[0];
```